# Github committing (push) gist

Tags: git, github, gist

I cannot understand this.

I have created a gist. Then I run

```
$ mkdir mygist
$ cd mygist
$ git init
$ git pull git@gist.github.com:869085.git
```

Then I add files, change files and try to commit.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Better comments"
```

Then I do not know how to send it back to github and commit this git.

Comment: I just wanted to a comment to anyone trying to do this: **You cannot add folders to a gist** (Or least I couldn't when I tried). I couldn't push if I tried to add a folder to the gist which lead me to believe the answers below didn't work. But they do, just don't commit folders.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this whilst trying to push over https, check if you have 2FA enabled, then you need to generate a token to push: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/

Answer (score 87):

It's probably easiest if you just start by cloning the gist, so that `origin` (a "remote" that refers to the original repository) is set up for you.  Then you can just do `git push origin master`.  For example:

```
git clone git@gist.github.com:869085.git mygist
cd mygist
# Make your changes...
git add .
git commit -m "Better comments"
git push origin master
```

However, if you don't want to redo your changes, you can do:

```
cd mygist
git remote add origin git@gist.github.com:869085.git
git fetch origin
# Push your changes, also setting the upstream for master:
git push -u origin master
```

Strictly speaking, the `git fetch origin` and `-u` argument to `git push origin master` are optional, but they will helpfully associate the upstream branch `master` in `origin` with your local branch `master`.

Comment: Thai is what I was trying to do but when I do 

$ git push origin master

I get 

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
ERROR: Permission to 869085.git denied to MightyTechnologies/Mighty-Solution-CMS.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @Sergey: this is a guess, but it might be that you haven't added the public key from `/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the SSH public keys of the MightyTechnologies account?  Otherwise, perhaps some of [the advice here](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/) might help?

Comment: @JJD: your edit to this answer switched to using `git branch -u`, which was only introduced in git very recently (v1.8.0) so I've changed the answer to use `git push -u origin master`, which saves a command as well.

Comment: The important thing is the git address is of the form `git@...` not `http:...` as the obvious 'clone' field on the gist pages uses.

Answer (score 12):

Since you did not use `git clone` you have no remote set up. While Mark Longair's solution is the best, an alternative would be:

```
git push git@gist.github.com:869085.git
```

Comment: Thai is what I was trying to do but when I do `$ git push origin master` I get `Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa': ERROR: Permission to 869085.git denied to MightyTechnologies/Mighty-Solution-CMS. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `git push` command to send that to github.

Comment: Thai is what I was trying to do but when I do $ git push origin master I get Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa': ERROR: Permission to 869085.git denied to MightyTechnologies/Mighty-Solution-CMS. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Well the message is saying that you are not allowed to write on that git repository. Are you sure that your public specified on github is the right one?